# IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalConfiguration not present Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm trying to use `staticCompositionLocalOf` in Jetpack Compose according to this [article on Medium](https://gustav-karlsson.medium.com/extending-the-jetpack-compose-material-theme-with-more-colors-e1b849390d50).
This is my ProvidableCompositionLocal

```kotlin
val lightColors = lightColors(
    primary = LightColor.BackgroundWhite,
    primaryVariant = LightColor.ToolbarWhite,
    secondary = LightColor.FabBlue,
    secondaryVariant = LightColor.BackgroundWhite,
    surface = LightColor.SurfaceWhite,
    onPrimary = LightColor.TextBlack,
    onSecondary = LightColor.TextBlack,
    onSurface = LightColor.TextBlack
)

val darkColors = darkColors(
    primary = DarkColor.BackgroundBlue,
    primaryVariant = DarkColor.ToolbarBlue,
    secondary = DarkColor.FabGrey,
    secondaryVariant = DarkColor.BackgroundBlue,
    surface = DarkColor.SurfaceBlue,
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onSurface = Color.White
)

private val DarkColorPalette =
    Colors(
        material = darkColors,
        toolbar = DarkColor.ToolbarBlue,
        background = DarkColor.BackgroundBlue,
        surface = DarkColor.SurfaceBlue,
        fab = DarkColor.FabGrey,
        pink = DarkColor.Pink
    )

private val LightColorPalette =
    Colors(
        material = lightColors,
        toolbar = LightColor.ToolbarWhite,
        background = LightColor.BackgroundWhite,
        surface = LightColor.SurfaceWhite,
        fab = LightColor.FabBlue,
        pink = LightColor.Pink
    )

val TheColor: Colors
    @Composable
    @ReadOnlyComposable
    get() = LocalColors.current
}

val LocalColors = staticCompositionLocalOf { DarkColorPalette }
```

This is the wrapper around the normal Colors class provided by Compose class. The material variable is the normal Colors class.

```kotlin
data class Colors(
    val material: Colors,
    val toolbar: Color,
    val background: Color,
    val surface: Color,
    val fab: Color,
    val pink: Color
) {
    val primary: Color get() = material.primary
    val primaryVariant: Color get() = material.primaryVariant
    val secondary: Color get() = material.secondary
    val secondaryVariant: Color get() = material.secondaryVariant
//    val background: Color get() = material.background
//    val surface: Color get() = material.surface
    val error: Color get() = material.error
    val onPrimary: Color get() = material.onPrimary
    val onSecondary: Color get() = material.onSecondary
    val onBackground: Color get() = material.onBackground
    val onSurface: Color get() = material.onSurface
    val onError: Color get() = material.onError
    val isLight: Boolean get() = material.isLight
}
```

I have also provided it in my Theme function as shown below. I'm getting the `darkTheme` from Android DataStore

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BMICalculatorTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalColors provides colors) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors.material,
            typography = CabinTypography,
            shapes = Shapes,
            content = content
        )
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the below error but can't find any online resources that can help me fix it. In case any further information is needed, I would be more than happy to clarify. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalConfiguration not present
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.noLocalProvidedFor(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:123)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.access$noLocalProvidedFor(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$LocalConfiguration$1.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:44)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$LocalConfiguration$1.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:43)
        at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getCurrent(ValueHolders.kt:29)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.LazyValueHolder.getValue(ValueHolders.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.resolveCompositionLocal(Composer.kt:1895)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.consume(Composer.kt:1865)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.DarkTheme_androidKt.isSystemInDarkTheme(DarkTheme.android.kt:52)
        at com.octagon_technologies.bmicalculator.data.ThemeDataStore$isDarkMode$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:135)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ErrorsKt$catchImpl$$inlined$collect$1.emit(Collect.kt:134)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(SafeCollector.kt:15)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollectorKt$emitFun$1.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:77)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.internal.SafeCollector.emit(SafeCollector.kt:59)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$data$1$invokeSuspend$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:139)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__LimitKt$dropWhile$$inlined$unsafeFlow$1$lambda$1.emit(Collect.kt:137)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl.collect(StateFlow.kt:348)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlowImpl$collect$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:12)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performTrampolineDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.run(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:57)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

Comment: Let see type of DarkColorPalette and class description.

Comment: I've included the DarkColorPalette and class description

Comment: You have to create the kind of wrapper class like this and implement you own palette inside. After make you own pallete vars typed as this class.
https://gist.github.com/gustavkarlsson/af7deeb45b3aed0faae181157d4fbd04#file-mycolors-kt

Comment: I have the wrapper class as indicated in your Medium publication. Let me include it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be here:

```
... ThemeDataStore$isDarkMode$$inlined$map$1$2.emit(Collect.kt:135)
```

From the stack trace it looks like the `isSystemInDarkTheme` is being called inside a lambda passed to `collect()` which, since it is an `@Composable` function, it should only be called from another `@Composable` function and cannot be called inside a flow `collect()`.

The compiler should have reported this an error. Please consider reporting this as a compose compiler plugin bug.

Comment: Thanks. I had annotated a normal Flow function with @Composable but now I've fixed it.